# Is this possible to collapse "If Then Else" as methods?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to collapse blocks of the code (like "if ... endif") in Visual Studio 2010 as it can be done with methods?

Comment: What language services are we talking about ? In C# you could use the `#region SOME NAME ` and `#endregion` directives to make any range of lines collapsible.

Comment: Added a tag to answer your question. I wonder why this question has been downvoted...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it is. Select the code, then hit `Ctrl+M,Ctrl+H` (in the default config)

alternatively, right-click and go to Outlining -> Hide Selection.

Here's [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on this very feature, which apparently is not available for Visual Basic code.

Comment: Even if this is more a walk around this missing feature, this will do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this will allow you to collapse a section of code visibly in C#.

`#region Name of region`

`#endregion`

**However regions are often not used in practice**

Why? If a method has so much code in it you need to use regions then your methods are likely too large and you should consider splitting it up into smaller more managable methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use  following

**#region**

//Your code which you want to collapse

**#endregion**

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge, both language-specific conditional statements (C#, VB etc.) cannot be collapsed*, and just in case this is what you mean (I can't tell due to poor tagging), compilation conditionals can't be, either (other than when one condition isn't met).

You can use the ['Outlining'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) context menu to get numerous options for handling this kind of thing, though - no nice UI toggling stuff**.

You can ['regionate'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) your code, but this is easy to abuse.

<sub>*At least not 'by standard' or without some third party extension I don't know about.</sub>

<sub>**Until outlines are made, then you have UI features.</sub>

Comment: Not disagreeing at all, but I am curious what kind of abuse can come from `regionating` the code?  I know there are some people who don't like the feature, but I've always wondered where the idea of "abuse" originating.

Comment: It originates from the people who don't like it being used (to be considered _too much_). Like the 'no elephants' signs you never see: if it were a problem you'd see a sign, likewise here.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE doesn't inherently enable code-folding on structures within methods - but `#Region` / `#End Region` achieve this.