# Collapse Select Cases without Region?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2017 to collapse the code in a `Case` of a vb.net `Select` without adding `Region`s to each `Case`?

I am working on adding to some legacy code that has a `Select` that runs to about 1,500 lines... Not really interested in going through and adding `Region`s to every `Case` especially as it's pretty evident that others working on this code have no idea what they are

I see that by default there are no collapse markers but I'm hoping that there may be some setting where what can be collapsed can be adjusted maybe?

**EDIT:** Found I can select the Case body then Ctrl+M, H... Any better way than this that I can specifically set collapsability for `Case`s?

**EDIT:** I also found [this tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-166355.OutlineRegionMarge) but it dates from VS2010 so I'm thinking it likely won't work with VS2017. There are instructions on making onse own outliner [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197665.aspx) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24b51f3d-fdd3-4524-8c55-2216237413e6/vs2010-vbnet-automatic-outlining?forum=vbide) but that's more work than I have time for ATM.

Comment: `Any better way than this...`  With a 1500 line case statement, I would consider a dictionary (or set of them) or even a LookUp

Comment: I would address the code at hand if at all possible. That's a lot of lines.

Comment: @Plutonix If I had a choice I'd just do away with it altogether. There's actually only about 25 cases, but nothing calls functions anywhere, everything that a case should do is coded directly in the case body >.<

Comment: I probably will eventually refactor this entire application, but that's for after I have new functionality added as the application is in production and the new stuff is needed now.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code?rq=1. It may even be a duplicate but not sure if an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Bugs Sadly this does not work for Cases, except for using the already mentioned Ctrl+M,H. A lot of the info on SO already works for C# because the editor can collapse on `{}` blocks, but VB doesn't have these

Comment: Answer here says this is not supported for VB :( http://stackoverflow.com/a/15070387/1292918

Answer (score 10):

According to [this article](http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/02/13/expand-and-collapse-code-blocks-on-the-fly-in-visual-studio/) you can.

Select a code block and do Ctrl+M+H to mark as a foldable section. 
With Ctrl+M+U you can remove the marker.

It works in VS2015.